# Add information to table with linq and stored procedure at architecture 3layers

Tags: asp.net

I use stored procedures and Linq in my project. I want insert information users what is code?

I write my website with a 3 layers architecture.

My code at bll layer

```
public class Account
{
        #region private Account

        private int _ID;
        private string _Name;
        private string _Family;
        private string _Email;
        private string _Tel;
        private string _Username;
        private string _Password;

        #endregion

        #region public property

        public int ID
        {
            get { return _ID; }
            set { _ID = value; }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            set { _Name = value; }
        }

        public string Family
        {
            get { return _Family; }
            set { _Family = value; }
        }

        public string Email
        {
            get { return _Email; }
            set { _Email = value; }
        }

        public string Tel
        {
            get { return _Tel; }
            set { _Tel = value; }
        }

        public string Usernamr
        {
            get { return _Username; }
            set { _Username = value; }
        }

        public string Password
        {
            get { return _Password; }
            set { _Password = value; }
        }

        #endregion

        #region public method

        CARDDataContext db = new CARDDataContext(); 

        public void insertAccount()
        {
            db.insertAccount(_Name, _Family, _Email, _Tel, _Username, _Password);
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(" اطلاعات با موفقیت درج شد ");
        }  

        #endregion
}
```

My code insert button

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Account account=new Account();

    account.Name = TextBox1.Text; 
    account.Family = TextBox2.Text ;
    account.Email = TextBox3.Text ;
    account.Tel = TextBox4.Text ;
    account.Usernamr = TextBox5.Text;
    account.Password = TextBox6.Text;
    account.insertAccount();
```

My project error is

> throw new NotImplementedException();

My stored procedure is:

```
create procedure [dbo].[insertAccount]
(
    @Name nvarchar(50),
    @Family nvarchar(50),
    @Email nvarchar(50),
    @Tel nvarchar(50),
    @Username nvarchar(50),
    @Password nvarchar(50) )
as 
    set nocount on

    insert into Account (Name, Family, Email, Tel, Username, Password)
    values (@Name, @Family, @Email, @Tel, @Username, @Password)

    return
```

How and where to add insert account method?

This is insert account method :

```
public void insertAccount()
{
    db.insertAccount(_Name, _Family, _Email, _Tel, _Username, _Password);
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(" اطلاعات با موفقیت درج شد ");
}
```

I add insert account method. What's the problem my project?

Please help me.

Comment: kindly provide some detail information. [Or see how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: The error seems to be telling you that there is no insertAccount method.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on insertAccount(); and look for "Go to Definition"

If there is no definition, meaning there is no method with that name, you'll need to create it.